# What are the constraints for the coefficents of the basis states in quantum computing?

Tags: quantum-state, measurement, textbook-and-exercises

$\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left|#1\right>}$
It's known that the Kolmogorov axioms characterise a probability distribution:

1. Probability of an event is a non-negative real number.
2. The sum of all probabilities is 1.
3. The probability of disjoint events is the sum of their probabilities.

But when dealing with a quantum system, as far as I know:
the first axiom is relaxed to allow negative & complex numbers;
The second axiom is changed to "The sum of the squares of the coefficients is 1".

But if that was all, wouldn't this allow for the following 1-qubit system:
$$\ket{\phi}=i\ket{0}+\sqrt{2}\ket{1}$$
The probabilities do sum to 1: \begin{align*}
i^2+\sqrt{2}^2 &= -1 + 2\\
&= 1
\end{align*}
But interpreting the 'probabilities' as probabilities separately seems to be nonsensical: \begin{align*}
P(\ket{0}) &= -100\%\quad(?)\\
P(\ket{1}) &= \phantom{-}200\%\quad(?)
\end{align*}

So can this system exist in actuality, or is merely a mathematical curiosity?

Assuming the latter, and assuming we disallow such a system by positing "The magnitude of the squares of the coefficients must lie in the $[0,1]$ interval."

But also consider the following 2-qubit system:
$$\ket{\psi}=\frac{1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}\ket{00}+\frac{1-\sqrt{3}i}{2}\ket{01}+\ket{10}+\ket{11}$$
Again the probabilities do sum to 1: \begin{align*}
\Big(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}\Big)^2 + \Big(\frac{1-\sqrt{3}i}{2}\Big)^2 + 1^2 + 1^2 &=
\frac{1+2\sqrt{3}i-3}{4} + \frac{1-2\sqrt{3}i-3}{4} + 1 + 1\\
&= \frac{1-3+1-3}{4} + 2\\
&= \frac{-4}{4} + 2\\
&= 1
\end{align*}
And again, we have two states with probability of $100\%$.

Did I miss something?

Comment: You already found your error, but just to mention, don't be too quick to discard your "mathematical curiosity": you have nearly discovered [an alternative formulation of quantum physics](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_probability#Physics_and_mathematics).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left|#1\right>}$
I did miss something, assuming the following system: $$\ket{\chi} = \sum_i{\alpha_i\ket{\chi_i}}\quad; \alpha_i\in\mathbb{C}$$
The probability of the system being in state $\ket{\chi_j}$ is $|\alpha_i|^2$, not $\alpha_i^2$ (where $|x|$ is the magnitude/amplitude of $x$).

So the system $\ket{\phi}$ cannot exist, because the probabilities of the square of the amplitudes is equal to 3 not 1:\begin{align*}
|i|^2+|\sqrt{2}|^2 &= 1^2 + \sqrt{2}^2\\
&= 1 + 2\\
&= 3
\end{align*}

Likewise for the system $\ket{\psi}$:\begin{align*}
\Big|\frac{1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}\Big|^2 + \Big|\frac{1-\sqrt{3}i}{2}\Big|^2 + |1|^2 + |1|^2 &= 1^2 + 1^2 + 1^2 + 1^2\\
&= 1 + 1 + 1 + 1\\
&= 4
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

[Kolmogorovian Probability Theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qt-quantlog/) [Paragraph 3.3]

> Let `S` be a set, understood for the moment as the state-space of a
> physical system, and let `Σ` be a `σ`-algebra of subsets of `S`. We
> can regard each partition `E` of `S` into countably many pair-wise
> disjoint `Σ`-measurable subsets as representing a “coarse-grained”
> approximation to an imagined perfect experiment that would reveal the
> state of the system. Let `AΣ` be the test space consisting of all such
> partitions. Note that the outcome set for `AΣ` is the set `X=Σ∖{∅}` of
> non-empty `Σ`-measurable subsets of `S`. Evidently, the probability
> weights on `AΣ` correspond exactly to the countably additive
> probability measures on `Σ`.

Thus the last sentences explains that there is only 100% Probability of the overall system. And cannot be count together 1 + 1 = 2 in terms the possible maximum is 1.

---

@Sofviic: I saw you found a solution while writing my answer, I will post it in terms it can help also from another perspective. Also like your answer - upvote! Well done!